# Force RapidWeaver pages to master style

Tags: rapidweaver

I have a large Rapidweaver site where I'm trying to change the underlying theme. There are several hundred pages and many are not checked with "Use Master Theme".

Is there any way to effect a mass change so that all pages will be marked to use the master?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a theme change (changing the overall theme) it will ask you if you want to apply it to all pages when you select it. However, if it is a theme setting change then the answer is no, you will have to manually edit all the pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It may be a long summer.  I will try to change all pages as you suggest first. But I think I have mix of standard and customized themes in place.

Comment: Glad to help @DavidDelMonte - wish it was better news, but hopefully the process goes smoothly. Just remember to keep saving as you do it - I have had RapidWeaver crash on me when editing larger websites.